# Android netbeans textchange on button click

Tags: android

This might be simple but I have create a simple APP that change text of text view when button clicked. The apps debug properly but does not show the change.

What actually happen is this.

1. Apps debugs OK
2. Emulator show "Waiting debugger to attach"
3. Text does not change as button clicked

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code that is not working ? (Your main Activity) We need more informations to help you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Apps debug OK' ? Does 'waiting on Debugger to Attach' actually attach the debugger, or is it hangin there? as @TimothéeJeannin mentions: Without further information No-one is able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your have written `button_name.setOnClickListener(this);` if your `Activity` is implementing `onClickListener`.

you should do something like this.

```
package org.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Hello extends Activity {
    private Button button;
    private TextView text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        text = (Button) findViewById(R.id.text1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                text.setText("Something....");

            }
        });
    }
}
```

You need to run application like following.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply....apart from this another thing happening. Emulator ask for "Waiting for debugger attach".. Kindly let me know what should I do on this

Comment: rerun your application like i have shown image above.If it solves your issue your should accept above answer.

Comment: can you please send the email address of yours....as I can't add the entire code here...